# Scroll to Kendo Grid row on click - Getting an unexpected JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

So I made a change event for my Kendo Grid so it will scroll to the selected row when selected. Everything is great, except, I'm getting a JavaScript error.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`

Here's the JavaScript code that's making this happen.

```
    function onGridChange(e) {
        var scrollContentOffset = this.element.find("tbody").offset().top;
        var selectContentOffset = this.select().offset().top;
        var distance = selectContentOffset - scrollContentOffset;

        //    animate our scroll
        this.element.find(".k-grid-content").animate({
            scrollTop: distance
        }, 400);

        var grid = $("#kendo-grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.clearSelection();
    }
```

I don't get it. Everything works fine. Can I just suppress the JavaScript error or how do you think I should handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't really _just suppress_ it. Check what the values of `this.element.find("tbody").offset()` and `this.select().offset()` are.

Comment: Thank you. After some digging, I found that my issue was being caused by ```grid.clearSelection();```

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue.

Calling `grid.clearSelection()` was causing another hit to the `onGridChange()` event.

```
function onGridChange(e) {
    if (this.select().length > 0) {
            var scrollContentOffset = this.element.find("tbody").offset().top;
            var selectContentOffset = this.select().offset().top;
            var distance = selectContentOffset - scrollContentOffset;

            //    animate our scroll
            this.element.find(".k-grid-content").animate({
                scrollTop: distance
            }, 400);

            var grid = $("#kendo-grid").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.clearSelection();
        }
}
```